# Extension method for Sorting a DataTable

Tags: c#

I am trying to sort a DataTable with an extensionmethod.  If used in the code body this works fine:

```
DataView dv = dtSensors.DefaultView;
dv.Sort = "DeviceName";
dtSensors = dv.ToTable();
```

However, used like this it does not:

```
public static void SortTable(this DataTable dt, string sortColumn)
{
     DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
     dv.Sort = sortColumn;
     dt = dv.ToTable();
}
```

Why would the extension method not work in this case?

Thanks,

Peter

Comment: Extension Methods are just Syntax Sugar for static Methods. All limitations of Static Methods still apply. Including that function scope variables have no effect on the rest of the programm.

Comment: But you can change the properties of a control with an extension method, though?  For instance, this works fine:

    public static void CancelButtonText(this SimpleButton btn, int mode)
    {
            btn.Text = (mode == 1) ? "Cancel" : "Close";
     }

Comment: Static Methods can call all public members of anything handed in as a Argument. The same as any other function. So of course, Extension Methods can too.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning a new value to `dt` within the method, but that won't change the variable used when you call the method - it's a value parameter.

As a simple example of that:

```
using System;

static class Int32Extensions
{
    // This doesn't do what you might expect it to!
    public static void Increment(this int x)
    {
        x = x + 1;
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int x = 10;
        x.Increment();
        Console.WriteLine(x); // Still 10
    }
}
```

I would personally write the method to *return* the new table, modifying the name appropriately:

```
public static DataTable SortedBy(this DataTable dt, string sortColumn)
{
     DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
     dv.Sort = sortColumn;
     return dv.ToTable();
}
```

Then use it as:

```
table = table.SortedBy("columnName");
```

I'm *slightly* concerned as to whether the modification to `DefaultView` will persist in the original table - it's not ideal to have a method like this mutate the original object. It depends whether `DefaultView` creates a new view each time it's called...